# First time with this error - Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

This is my first time working with interfaces and proper namespace structure. When I compile I get the error below, I have no idea what it means. Any searches I do shows  up private public issues but both are public. Any ideas?

> Error  Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than method 'Webtext.ApplicationEntities.Implementations.AdditionalEntities.UrlBuilderO2.GetUrlRequests
>   (string, string, string, string)'   C:\Users\Laptop\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Webtext\Webtext\ApplicationEntities\Implementations\AdditionalEntities\UrlBuilderO2.cs    19  39  Webtext

The Code files are:

```
namespace Webtext.ApplicationEntities.Interfaces
{
    interface IUrlBuilder
    {
       List<IOperatorRequest> GetUrlRequests(string UserName, string Password, string MessageRecipient, string Message);
    }
}
```

And:

```
namespace Webtext.ApplicationEntities.Implementations.AdditionalEntities
{
    public class UrlBuilderO2: IUrlBuilder
    {

        public List<IOperatorRequest> GetUrlRequests(string UserName, string Password, string MessageRecipient, string Message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Namespace Structure

```
Webtext

ApplicationEntities

     Interfaces
          ##### INTERFACE IS HERE

     Implementations

          AdditionalEntities
               ##### URL BUILDER IS HERE
```

Comment: What is the accessibility of IOperatorRequest?

Comment: Namespaces are irrelevant here.

Comment: those two files are the same. were you meaning to show the interface?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, Im getting used to the formatting.

Comment: @DeanMc - please show the code for `IOperatorRequest`.

Comment: Sorry im a bit slow using this markup. The issue was access, a change to public fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `public` property on a `public` class that exposes a list of non-`public` types.
You need to change `IOperatorRequest` to be `public` or change the `UrlBuilderO2` class or `GetUrlReuests` method to be non-`public`.

Comment: Your class has a public method that gives a list of non-public interfaces.  If you call that method from outside the project, what would happen?

Comment: @Slaks is right. He's guessing, but im also guessing that he's right (your problem is `IOperatorRequest`).

Comment: I was under the impression that Interfaces are public by default. I changed the interface to public but no change.

Comment: Gave the tick to you as you answered correctly first it was my fault I didn't get it.

Comment: Come on I guessed it correctly, I knew you had missed the modifier.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `IOperatorRequest` is probably `internal`.

**UPDATE**

What I said is correct. [Omitting modifier makes it internal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.

Comment: No what I said is correct. Omitting modifier makes it internal.

Answer (score 2):

`IOperatorRequest` is `internal` which is less accessible than `public`.

> Top-level types, which are not nested
>   in other types, can only have internal
>   or public accessibility. *The default
>   accessibility for these types is
>   **internal**.*

[from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)